# Section and Row not properly displayed in UITableView Swift

Tags: ios, json, swift, uitableview

I am trying to implement sections and rows in UITableView but because of nested JSON model structure I am not successful. It always print only `first section title`. I am using `Codable` approach and model structure cannot be changed.

How can I achieve sections & rows in `tableView`? any guidance or help would be really appreciate. I am really struggling for this.

- I need to display in tableView Section are `title` and Rows `textField` -- see JSON.
- screenshot attached which print only one `section title`

Model:

```
struct SectionList : Codable {

    let title : String?
    var items : [Item]?

}

struct Item : Codable {

    let actionType : Int?
    var textField : String?
    let pickList: [SectionList]?
    let itemValue: String?
    let version: Int?

}
```

Initialization & TableView code:

```
var AppData: [Item]?

let decoder = JSONDecoder()
let response = try decoder.decode(SectionList.self, from: pickResult)
let res = response.items?.filter { $0.actionType == 101}
self.AppData = res


func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return AppData?.count ?? 0
    }

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
   return AppData?[section].pickList[0].title
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return AppData?[section].pickList?.count ?? 0
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = UITableViewCell()
    let dic = AppData?[indexPath.section]//.pickList?[indexPath.row].title
        //AppData?[indexPath.section].pickList[indexPath.row].items
    //print(dic)

    return cell 
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whatever I understand by you, I make it. Check this code

**Create struct as**

```
struct SectionList : Codable {

    let title : String?
    var items : [RowItems]?

}

struct RowItems: Codable {
    var textField : String?
    let itemValue: String?
}

struct SourceData: Codable {
    let items: [Item]?
}
struct Item : Codable {
    let actionType : Int?
    let pickList: [SectionList]?
    let version: Int?

}
```

**Create variable like**

```
var AppData: Item?
```

**Parse json as**

```
let decoder = JSONDecoder()
            let response = try decoder.decode(SourceData.self, from: data)
            let res = response.items?.filter { $0.actionType == 101}
            print("jsonData:\(res)")
            AppData = res?.first
```

**Call table data source as**

```
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return AppData?.pickList?.count ?? 0
    }

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
    return AppData?.pickList?[section].title
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return AppData?.pickList?[section].items?.count ?? 0
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = UITableViewCell()
    let dic = AppData?.pickList?[indexPath.section].items?[indexPath.row]//.pickList?[indexPath.row].title
        //AppData?[indexPath.section].pickList[indexPath.row].items
    //print(dic)

    cell.textLabel?.text = dic?.textField
    return cell
}
```

**Screenshot with this code** 
[image: Table after this changes]

Comment: Reference to your answer, Can I ask one question which is related to searchBar?. If I use `TextField` as a searchBar how can I filter data can you guide me for this? data is same.

Comment: On which basis you want to filter data? textField?

Comment: same `TextField` value which is displaying 
`let dic = AppData?.pickList?[indexPath.section].items?[indexPath.row]`
`dic?.textField`.

Comment: Ok I will create new post Thank you.

Comment: Ok, Share link here.

Comment: Thank you and here is the link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60191056/how-to-implement-textfield-search-bar-to-filter-tableview-values-swift

Comment: I have the working and tested solution for this, i will post it on question.

Comment: Please check, I have answered on post.

Comment: Thank you so much. I have added special comments for you. such a great learning.

Comment: Pardon me I am disturbing you again, I don't feel good but one thing I wanna ask because you knows the model structure. My question is How can I add section on the top of the tableView? actually I have already written code for adding row and its working and add row  but in same section but I want to add top section like `Selected` section and when I execute codes for add new section thing it gives me error.

Answer (score -1):

your Model should be like

```
import Foundation

    // MARK: - Items
    struct Items: Codable {
        let items: [ItemsItem]?
    }

    // MARK: - ItemsItem
    struct ItemsItem: Codable {
        let actionType, version: Int?
        let pickList: [PickList]?
    }

    // MARK: - PickList
    struct PickList: Codable {
        let title: String?
        let items: [PickListItem]?
    }

    // MARK: - PickListItem
    struct PickListItem: Codable {
        let textField, itemValue: String?
    }
```

your varibale should be like this

```
var appData : Items?
```

during decode just add this

```
appData = try decoder.decode(Items.self, from: pickResult)
```

your table view delegate and data source should be like

```
  func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
                return appData?.items?.first?.pickList?.count ?? 1
            }
            func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
                let cell = UITableViewCell()
                return appData?.items?.first?.pickList?.first?.title
            }
            func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
                return appData?.items?.first?.pickList?[section].items?.count ?? 1
            }

            func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
                let cell = UITableViewCell()
                cell.textLabel?.text = appData?.items?.first?.pickList?.first?.items?[indexPath.row].textField
                return cell
            }
```