# How to implement TextField search bar to filter tableview values Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uitextfield, uisearchcontroller

I have created a custom textField bar on top of the ViewController to filter data values in `UITableView`. As I have a nested type of JSON so couldn't properly get how to use filter for it.

- I want to implement `textField` as a search bar with TableView. screenshot attached.
- Value which I need to filter is `pickList -> textField`
- `textSearchChange` function added for text search.

Data is section wise and then values and is already displaying in tableView.

Model:

```
struct SectionList : Codable {

    let title : String?
    var items : [Item]?

}

struct PickListData: Codable {
    let items: [Item]?
}

struct Item : Codable {

    let actionType : Int?
    var textField : String?
    var pickList: [SectionList]?
    var selection: [Item]?
    let selectedValue: [String]?
    let version: Int?
    let masterId: Int?
    let itemValue: String?
}
```

ViewController Code:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var searchTxt: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
    var AppData: Item?
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self
        searchTxt.delegate = self
        readDataList()
    }
    func readDataList(){

        if let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "list", withExtension: "json") {
            do {

                let data = try Data(contentsOf: url)
                let decoder = JSONDecoder()
                let response = try decoder.decode(PickListData.self, from: data)
                let res = response.items?.filter { $0.actionType == 101}
                AppData = res?.first
                print(AppData)
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            } catch {
                print("error:\(error)")
            }
        }

    }

    @IBAction func textSearchChange(_ sender: UITextField) {
        print("search")
    }


}

extension ViewController: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return AppData?.pickList?.count ?? 0
        }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
        return AppData?.pickList?[section].title
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return AppData?.pickList?[section].items?.count ?? 0
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = UITableViewCell()
        let dic = AppData?.pickList?[indexPath.section].items?[indexPath.row]//.pickList?[indexPath.row].title
            //AppData?[indexPath.section].pickList[indexPath.row].items
        //print(dic)

        cell.textLabel?.text = dic?.textField
        return cell
    }

}
```

JSON Data:

```
{
  "items": [
    {
      "actionType": 101,
      "version": 3,
      "pickList": [
        {
          "title": "Sayaç yeri seçimi",
          "items": [
            {
              "textField": "Sayaç Yeri Seçiniz",
              "itemValue": "0"
            },
            {
              "textField": "Sayaç daire girişinde",
              "itemValue": "1"
            },
            {
              "textField": "Sayaç apt. girişinde",
              "itemValue": "2"
            },
            {
              "textField": "Sayaç bodrumda",
              "itemValue": "3"
            },
            {
              "textField": "Sayaç çatı katında",
              "itemValue": "4"
            },
            {
              "textField": "Sayaç bahçede (Müstakil)",
              "itemValue": "5"
            },
            {
              "textField": "Sayaç bina dışında",
              "itemValue": "6"
            },
            {
              "textField": "Sayaç balkonda",
              "itemValue": "7"
            },
            {
              "textField": "Sayaç daire içinde",
              "itemValue": "8"
            },
            {
              "textField": "Sayaç istasyon içinde",
              "itemValue": "9"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
]
}
```

**Updated Code:** but this is wrong I want to search with `TextField`

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
        let searchText  = textField.text! + string

        Filterdata = (AppData?.pickList?.filter({(($0.title!).localizedCaseInsensitiveContains(searchText))}))!

         if(Filterdata.count == 0){
           isSearch = false
         }else{
           isSearch = true
        }
         self.tableView.reloadData();

         return true
    }
```

Image:
[image: searchTableView]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please follow this steps for the working solution

*** Step 1 -> Replace struct**

```
    struct SectionList : Codable {
        let title : String?
        var items : [RowItems]?
        mutating func filterData(string: String) {
            self.items = self.items?.filter({ (item) -> Bool in
                if item.textField?.contains(string) == true {
                    return true
                }
                return false
            })
        }
    }

    struct Item : Codable {
        let actionType : Int?
        var pickList: [SectionList]?
        let version: Int?
        mutating func filterData(string: String) {
            guard var tempList = pickList else { return }
            for index in 0..<tempList.count {
                tempList[index].filterData(string: string)
            }
            pickList = tempList
        }
    }
```

*** Step 2 -> Create one more variable to hold original data**

```
    var globalAppData: Item?
```

*** Step 3 -> Assign value to globalAppData while you parsing json**

```
    let res = response.items?.filter { $0.actionType == 101}
    AppData = res?.first
    globalAppData = AppData
```

*** Step 4 -> Add observer for text change**

```
    searchTxt.addTarget(self, action: #selector(textSearchChange(_:)), for: .editingChanged)
```

*** Step 5 -> Replace textDidChange method**

```
    @IBAction func textSearchChange(_ sender: UITextField){

        var tempData = globalAppData
        if let text = sender.text, text.isEmpty == false {
        tempData?.filterData(string: text)
        }
        AppData = tempData

        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
```

*** Optional Step 6 ->**

If you want case insensitive search then replace this line

```
    item.textField?.contains(string)
```

with

```
    item.textField?.lowercased().contains(string.lowercased())
```

Comment: Honestly its so perfect solution, little complex one but it works smoothly. Big thanks for this but this is also a great learning to work with struct like this way.

Comment: But whenever you have time please do explain `mutating func` concept. Thank you.

Comment: It's great to have such kind of comments. Sure I will explain.

Answer (score 1):

//You need to apply action Sent Event is editing changed

[image]

```
@IBAction func actionTextChange(_ sender: UITextField) {
    print("get text -----\(sender.text)")

}
```

Comment: Thank you Yes this thing I have already done that setting `outlet Event`

Answer (score 0):

In the method `textSearchChange`
you have the query string `sender.text`. You should filter the result
and store it to another array. Then you can use the `filteredResultArray` in the tableView delegate. And every time you modify the `filteredResultArray` you should reload your tableView.

Comment: Thank you yes I have tried like this but not working. 
`tableFilterdata = [AppData!]` and then `Filterdata = tableFilterdata.filter({($0.textField?.contains(searchTxt.text!))!}) `

Comment: you should reload the tableView after modifying the filteredData